Ubuntu Grub still can't detect CentOS install after update-grub
I have an old PC (Dell Optiplex 990) that I'm trying to repurpose into a Linux machine to get more familiar with Linux.
I'm setting it up as a dual boot machine (Ubuntu 22.04, CentOS 7). The system is BIOS Legacy MBR.
I already installed Ubuntu 22.04 (with its own /boot partition on /dev/sda1 and root (/) on sda2. Bootloader on /dev/sda.
I then installed CentOS, /boot is on sda3 and root (/) on sda4. I deselected the bootloader installation on this one  since I didn't want to override the one already installed bootloader when I installed Ubuntu earlier.
I then went to boot Ubuntu and did the changes for grub to be able to detect my CentOS installation; enabled OS probe and updated grub sudo update-grub.
However, grub still can't detect my CentOS installation and doesn't list it, it only shows Ubuntu options in the grub boot menu.
Does anyone know what the issue might be and the workaround for it? Thank you so much.

You would need to at a place where Linux users use all kinds of versions as they will likely know CentOS (it is not even a debian version so works fairly different) We only accept official Ubuntu and since that one seems to work ... Please use our sister site at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

@Rinzwind Thank you for the heads up. I'll try to ask there.

Ensure your /etc/devault/grub has GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

@ubfan1 I already tried setting GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false before I did sudo update-grub. But when I restarted, grub still wasn't able to detect CentOS, only the Ubuntu options were listed in the grub boot menu.

You're skipping essential details.. for an OS to see what is inside other partitions & correctly identify it, the file-system in use really matters., You don't mention what fs you use, and whether or not it's a fs that the grub scan is capable of successfully scanning... so I suggest you explore what you are using there, and if you want help with that, we need that detail too.  You can see what is scanned successfully when you run update-grub & clues are shown there!!  Does what you see there reflect what you see on reboot?  If it doesn't you're missing the next issue...

I went for a workaround instead (used CentOS grub bootloader and grub instead).
I went to install CentOS grub bootloader in the MBR (replaced Ubuntu'a grub) via live USB grub-install. I'm now using CentOS' grub2.
For some reason, Ubuntu's grub-mkconfig and os-probe is able to find the kernel of CentOS but wasn't able to write them into the /boot/grub/grub.cfg config when I tried to check after executing sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg. (note, I've already set GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false in etc/default/grub).

When I installed CentOS' grub, I was able to find my Ubuntu install from CentOS using grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg and os-probe was able to find and write the detected Linux installs into /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
I also just installed 2 other distros (Debian 11, Fedora 38) and was able to successfully add them to CentOS' /boot/grub/grub.cfg and can boot into those distros successfully.

@guiverc The hard disk is set to MBR/DOS. For my Ubuntu and CentOS installs, I used ext4 (primary) for both /boot and root (/). For my preceeding installs (I installed additional distros after going for CentOS' grub instead), I'm using a separate hard disk that's extend logical ext4.
